# Can i call methods inside string template in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a method:

```
fun sum(first:Int, second:Int):Int
{
    return first + second
}
```

Can I call this method with parameter inside a string template like I can do with a variable?

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
println("$sum(3,4)")
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Addition @OP: if you're asking this because you don't have access to a Kotlin environment, you can use sites like [Ideone](http://www.ideone.com).

Comment: I've tried this ``println("$sum(3,4)")``

Comment: These down votes are atrocious, this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Probably because you didn't include your failed attempt, and didn't show any effort.

Comment: The OP obviously did make an effort but its a useful bad example for searchable documentation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) can contain arbitrary expressions, you just have to use curly braces.

```
fun foo() = 42
val bar = 25

"$bar"
"${bar}"
"${foo()}"
"${2 + 10 / 5}"
```